# Constantly having to kill worker processes to start up my Phoenix app

Tags: react-redux, phoenix-framework

I am currently working on a Phoenix backend with React-Redux frontend application. My task is to develop a new component, but I am starting to get annoyed with having to run this all the time:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:3000
$ kill -9 PID
```

because if not it tells me `Something is already running on port 3000`.

I get this message in terminal even when its just the Chrome browser with docs in the background. I don't want to have to shut down my browser worker processes just to start this app and I have never seen this behavior before.

Where could the problem lie? Keep in mind I did not build this application, and that I am fairly new to the Phoenix framework.

At any given time when I did an `lsof -i tcp:3000` these are the processes running:

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE   DEVICE       SIZE/OFF     NODE        NAME
node 13691 username 24u IPv4 0x19aa008389bcc55 0t0 TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

So in `dev.exs` it shows `port: 4000` but thats the Phoenix backend, there is also a React-Redux frontend running on port 3000 so I don't believe changing the port on the Phoenix backend would help in this case.

Comment: What is the process that is running on port 3000 exactly? Please provide more information.

Comment: Check your `dev.exs` file for the `port` key to see which port phoenix is using. You can change the port as you need there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution by running this script before starting up Phoenix:

`lsof -i :3000 | awk '$1 == "node" { print $2 }' | uniq | xargs kill -9`

`lsof` - list open files

`| awk '$1 == "node" { print $2 }` - dollar sign indicates column 1 equals node, if it is grab the PID, unique-ing it so it can kill property and pass the PID and kill it.